# Engine won't turn over without key fob

Tags: honda, starting, fob

I have a 2006 Honda Accord. The key fob broke off and I tried starting my car without it, but the engine does not turn over. It works fine with my spare key.

The obvious explanation is that I'm not applying enough torque, because there's only a little stub of a key sticking out. But I really am cranking it all the way, so it seems hard to believe. Is there any other reason my key wouldn't turn over the engine without the fob?

Comment: Does the old fob have a chip in it. You may want call a Honda dealer and ask if the fob has a chip that in needed to start the car.

Comment: @AlaskaMan can you expand that comment into an answer, as I'd say that's exactly what's wrong, a passive chip in the fob disarming the immobilizer.

Comment: Yes, @AlaskaMan is correct. There is a wedge shaped ceramic transponder chip also built inside the case of the key not just the keyless entry controls. You should call a reputable locksmith to get a new key and programming done. Your car will not crank, fire or provide fuel without out a properly coded transponder. The car is immobilized. This is stock on all accords since about 1998.